# Abaqus Surface getSequenceFromMask

Tags: python, mask, surface, abaqus

I am writing script in Abaqus, where I crush circle and square with cut circle (like cheese). I need to put Contact between parts so I need Surface.

macro manager generates:

```
s1 = a.instances['kolo-1'].edges
side1Edges1 = s1.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )
a.Surface(side1Edges=side1Edges1 , name='kolkoSurf')
```

The problem is: getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )
How to get this #1? Can I replace it? I searched little and there were some ideas to use: 'find', 'face', 'COORDS' but I cannot manage it. 
Please help me. I dream to get an simple example how to extract this Surface using X, Y or anyway.

BR,
Wonman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You recorded the above journal using the macro manager with default journal options. Therefore, the variable `side1Edges1` is defined in your journal using the `getSequenceFromMask()`-method. This method is the recording of the selection you performed by clicking the GUI during the recording. This means you clicked the GUI to select an edge and the result is the `getSequenceFromMask()`-method acting on `s1` which is a set of all edges of the instance `'kolo-1'`.

According to Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide 6.14 - 7.2.2 the method `getSequenceFromMask()` is highly efficient when a large number of objects are involved. However, this is not very helpful if your trying to customize your journal file to select another geometry element to work with. There are two solutions:

1. Solution: Paste the command

   ```
   session.journalOptions.setValues(replayGeometry=COORDINATE, recoverGeometry=COORDINATE)
   ```

   into the Abaqus command line at the bottom of Abaqus CAE to set the members `replayGeometry` and `recoverGeometry` of your JournalOptions object to `COORDINATE` and repeat the recording of your journal. 
   You can, most of the time, omit clicking the GUI again by executing your old journal after issuing the command above.
   You can then save your project, preferably with a new name, and use the newly created journal.
   In the new journal the command `getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )` will by replaced by a selection based on coordinates to represent your recorded GUI-click. 
   You can then modify the coordinates in order to customize your journal file and to select the edge you like to use in subsequent modeling steps.
2. Solution: Define `side1Edges1` using variables you defined from Scratch in the preceding lines of your python script. I recommend using the journal file as a blueprint in which all click-events have to be replaced using well known variables, defined by yourself. For example, define a list of points `myPoints = [(0,0), (0,1) ]` using your own logic and then use these points as arguments of the methods e.g. `myLine = mySketch.Line(point1=myPoints[0], point2=myPoints[1])`, constructing new variables like `myLine` for the usage in subsequent modeling steps.

To get a basic understanding of the modeling workflow using the Abaqus Python API, i can recommend 
Puri, G. M., 2011. Python scripts for Abaqus : learn by example, 1st Edition, also it is hardly available in most universities.

Looking at the Abaqus Benchmark Guide can be helpful, as some newer Benchmarks contain Python scripts (e.g. Fracture Mechanics).

Comment: It seems there is no such a constant `COORDINATES` in Abaqus 6.14. But `COORDINATE` works fine.

Comment: @JKepler Thank you, I corrected my answer by changing 'COORDINATES' to 'COORDINATE'.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are creating an edge based surface. There are many ways to do it, easiest one is

Create an assembly based set ("setName") of those edges for which you want to create surface.

```
instance=mdb.rootAssembly.instances["InstanceName"]
set_for_surface=instance.sets["setName"].edges
assembly.Surface(side1Edges=set_for_surface, name="surf_name")
```

Have look at findAt() or selecting region by bounding box "getBoundingBox()". See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856474/selecting-multiple-partitioned-regions-in-abaqus-with-findat-for-setting-mesh-co/38883235#38883235), which is somewhat similar.

Edit: If the set is an assembly based set, access it directly from assembly not instance. Then, use the same procedure.

```
mdb.rootAssembly.sets['Set_name'].edges
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer but i found simpler way to select all the edges by giving coordinates:

```
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
e = p.edges
edges = e.getByBoundingBox(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)
p.Set(edges=edges, name='AllPartSet')
```

x, y and z are two coordinates for making a box.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, the getByBoundingBox function return a mask string (if the element set is not empty), which can be used in getSequenceFromMask to create sets and surfaces.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35455417)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution is:

```
s1 = a.instances['kolo-1'].edges
side1Edges1 = s1.getSequenceFromMask(s1.getMask())
a.Surface(side1Edges=side1Edges1 , name='kolkoSurf')
```